# Why this is showing error ? even though it seems all syntax is correct?

Tags: c++11

I was writing a c++ code then encountered this error, how to resolve this ?
[image]

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string str="([])[]({})";
    char a[10];
    int stk[10], total=0;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        a[i]=str[i];
        cout<<a[i];
        if(a[i]=="[" || a[i]=="{" || a[i]=="("){
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put single ticks around the items being compared: `'['` instead of `"["`.  That way you are comparing `char` to `char` instead of `char` to a string

Comment: oh okay :-)  , this means single quotes for char only ?

Comment: @T.Y.M.SAI  yes, correct